# MP Android chart X axis scaling via Seekbar

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart, seekbar

In MP android chart there is a cool function called "Scale X" which expands or contracts the bars & x-axis in a standard barchart and X-axis via two finger pinch gestures.

What I'm trying to do is make a function that can ideally adjust the scale of the chart via SeekBar(slider control), but the problem with it is the chart(graphics wise), doesn't always invalidate when contracting the bars mostly when reaching 1.0f(initial X scale value for the chart).

The main reason why I want this function is to help the users who either don't have finger scaling gestures devices or prefer to use mouses of some kind(Examples of these devices are micro USB, USB hubs that hook up to keyboards, Bluetooth mouses, or computers that run off android like the google pixel book).

Lastly you can easily plug this code below and make these simple changes in into "BarChartActivity.java" on MPAndroid chart from github

- I removed the xml seekbar's "android:max="200""
- mSeekBarX.setMax(50);
- Set mChart.setScaleXEnabled(true);
- float floatVal is a global variable with a intial value of 0.0f;

My implementation of `onProgressChanged()`:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

    try {
        if(progress != 0){
            floatVal = 1.0f + progress * 0.1f;
            //floatVal = Math.round(floatVal);
            System.out.println("Progress #3: val " + floatVal);
            mChart.setScaleX(floatVal);
            System.out.println("Mchart Scale X value: " + mChart.getScaleX());

            //mChart.invalidate();

        }
        else{
            mChart.setScaleX(1.0f);
            mChart.invalidate();
        }

        System.out.println("Progress " + progress);
        System.out.println("Seekbar progress " + mSeekBarX.getProgress());


    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```